# Reversed up-sell

Tags: backend, up-sells

Now, in the backend edit page of `ProductA`, the Up-sell tab shows the products that will display in the up-sell block when we visit `ProductA` page.

I would like to add a tab in the product edit page. This tab would be what I can call reversed Up-sells (or down-sell). It will list the product where `ProductA` is an Up-sell, and ideally would be editable the same way Up-sells tab is.

Do you know any extension doing that or should I start the development?

Using Magento CE 1.7.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-accessories.html). It says it works on versions up to 1.6, but it should work on 1.7 and later also.
By default this extension adds a new product association called 'Accessories' but you can change the labels to be called 'down-sells' or what ever you want.
On think you should be careful at. I wrote that extension eons ago, when I was still learning Magento and I've rewritten the product model. Now I know that there is a better way to do id, but didn't get the chance to do it. Anyway...if nothing else rewrites the product model it should work nicely.

Comment: Thanks Marius, but that is not exactly what I need. I do not want to add a product relation, I want to use the existing one but "see" it from the other end of the relation.

Comment: a good usecase that might help to understand : If I set a product as End of Life (in my workflow, I just have a custom attribute that will hide the price and add to cart of the EOL products but keep them in catalog for userguide and support purpose), I do not want to up-sell it anywhere anymore. but with the existing I have no choice but to see all other products and whether my EOL product is as Up-sell or not. Well, the additional tab I want would do the search job for me and I can just unset from there.

Comment: I understand now. the line "and ideally would be editable the same way Up-sells tab is" is the one that threw me off. I'll see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: Did you got anything?

Comment: Sorry. I have nothing for now